# not able to push repo through git to github

Tags: git, github

I want to push my local repo of my PC to a remote server in Github
so for doing so I first

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "message"
3. git remote -v and git branch (To check my remote uRL and branch)
4. git push "remote name" "master name"

But on doing so I am getting error like this shown in the figure.
So at what part I am doing wrong. Hoping to get suggestions as soon as possible

[Git bash Coomand line commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Plxr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing it on branch master, try the following -

1. `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` (This will pull latest from master and
   merge with current chages, you may encounter a conflict)
2. `git add .` (Add any changes optional if you change anything the do a `git commit -m "message"`).
3. `git push -u origin master`

This will sync changes with remote repository.

Comment: $ git pull gettobyte_youtube_codes master
From github.com:gkunalupta/Gettobyte_Youtube
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
****fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories***                                           I am getting this error on pulling my repo, I think their is some issue with permissions, but cant figure out what is it

Comment: I have updated the answer  with  `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` please check.

Comment: ohh yes man it works.  can u please tell how does it work and overcome this error